# javascript encode base64 for persian language & characters

Tags: c#, javascript, base64, decode, json

I have a website that is in Persian language (only the content), and I'm doing AJAX calls here and there, but the problem I'm encountering is that I encode the data (let's say user info) that I'm sending to server via my AJAX call with base64 but when I'm gonna decode it on server side (C#), I'm getting an error. I assume it's because I'm encoding non-English characters.

Here is my encoder:

```
var keyStr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP" +
            "QRSTUVWXYZabcdef" +
            "ghijklmnopqrstuv" +
            "wxyz0123456789+/" +
            "=";

function encode64(input) {
    var output = "";
    var chr1, chr2, chr3 = "";
    var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4 = "";
    var i = 0;

    do {
        chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
        chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
        chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);

        enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
        enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
        enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
        enc4 = chr3 & 63;

        if (isNaN(chr2)) {
            enc3 = enc4 = 64;
        } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
            enc4 = 64;
        }

        output = output +
        keyStr.charAt(enc1) +
        keyStr.charAt(enc2) +
        keyStr.charAt(enc3) +
        keyStr.charAt(enc4);
        chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = "";
        enc1 = enc2 = enc3 = enc4 = "";
    } while (i < input.length);

    return output;
}
```

Well it works just fine when the content is in English but fails when in Persian, 
here's the server side code:

```
byte[] userByteArr = System.Convert.FromBase64String(jsonUser);
string userStr = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(userByteArr);
JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var deserialized_user = (IDictionary<string,object>)jsSerializer.DeserializeObject(userStr);
```

Comment: You're reading the string as ASCII, so it won't work.  You'll need to change that for it to render properly.

Comment: It gives error at first line:
    byte[] userByteArr = System.Convert.FromBase64String(jsonUser);
it says "Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string."

Comment: Hmm...  Anyway that's still a problem.  I'll take a further look into it.